# What are the best practices for consuming Java Web Services from dotnet

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services

There are two ways we can use to consume Java Web Services ..using Dotnet Web Services or WCF. Can someone point out the benefits of doing one way or the other ?

Comment: You're going to _consume_ a web service with another web service? I'm not sure that's a method of _consuming_ a web service as it sounds like an end goal of _wrapping_ a web service.

Comment: `There are two ways` I wouldn't be so sure. WebClient+XmlParser could work too.

Comment: What protocol is your java webservice using?
If you are spitting out json or xml in a rest interface, using WCF to interface with it will be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a soap web service you just need to add a service reference to the url in .NET

> URL example:

```
 http://host:9232/Calculator/CalculatorServiceService?wsdl
```

[image]:

Since Java EE Web Services (JAX-WS) are **standard SOAP services**, they are easily interoperable from a .Net client application with only several clicks. Visual Studio generated a .Net client proxy that makes it very easy to connect and call the service.

Webservice Call Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CalculatorServiceClient proxy = new CalculatorServiceClient();
    int result = proxy.Add(2, 3);
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator Service returned: " + result.ToString());
}
```